# Is there a way to call imported functions in the debug console?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm debugging some typescript/javascript code on Visual Studio Code and it's been very helpful!

However I cannot call functions that are imported in the code being run. Let's say I have this in the code:
`variable = getVariable();`

I can type `variable` in the debug console and it returns the variable that was just defined in the code, however if I try to just call the function `getVariable()` I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: getVariable is not defined`

I'd love to be able to call all the functions that work in the code also in the debug console.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using build tools it might change names of some variables in runtime. You can always check it in "variables" tab in "debug" panel. It'll show you all variables available in your current scope. Imports are usually next to the "global" scope.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @АлексейМартинкевич but I still can't find the functions there. Maybe this info might help you: the scope I'm in when trying to execute this function in debug mode is inside a function export `export const otherFunction = (...){};`

Comment: What is yours "variables" tab looks like? Can you attach screenshot please?

Comment: Sure, thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f101w7373sku6i/screen%20shot%202021-02-20%20at%2021.06.12.png

Answer (score 0):

Imported variables get renamed because of the bundling process and to ensure ecmascript compatibility. There exists a [webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin) (written by me) which will simplify the debugging experience in most cases. It's limitations are

- no full ecma script compatibility (no live bindings)
- imported vars are defined asyncronously (meaning the will not be available during the first code execution)

if that's ok for you you can install the plugin with

`npm i debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin`

and insert it into you `webpack.config.js` and after a restart `getVariable ()` should be available.